# $2f(S\cup T\cup V)\leq f(S\cup T)+f(T\cup V)+f(V\cup S)$ for subadditive set function?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given a set $A$, let $f$ be a [subadditive set function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subadditive_set_function): $f(S\cup T)\leq f(S)+f(T)$ for all $S,T\subseteq A$.

Is it true that $2f(S\cup T\cup V)\leq f(S\cup T)+f(T\cup V)+f(V\cup S)$ for all $S,T,V\subseteq A$?

If we use the subadditive condition, we get $f(S\cup T)+f(T\cup V)\geq f(S\cup T\cup V)$, but this does not give us the inequality in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let $A=\{0,1,2\}$, and for $F\subset X$ define $f(F)$ to be $0$ if $F$ is empty, $1$ if $F$ has one or two elements, and $2$ if $F=A$. Looking at various cases shows that $f$ is subadditive (*unless* it doesn't; you want to check this carefully lest I missed one). Now let $S$, $U$, and $T$ be the three singletons and note that $4>3$.